# how to show local temprature

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I m working on a MVC Project in which I want to show temperature of the local region from where the page is requested, can anyone tell me how to do this using local IP address.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't look for a method in .NET like `int GetTemperature(string ip)`, you won't find any. Look for an API on the internet that you could query and which will give you this information. You may take a look for example at the [`Yahoo Weather API`](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/).